# Destroy PHP Session by value of a variable stored in Session

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, php-7

I am using `ZF1` and `PHP7` in my project.

I am setting session as follows during login

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace()
$session->email = 'example@example.com' //recieved via login form
```

Now, somewhere in my code, due to my use case, I want to destroy the session which has `$session->email` as `example@example.com`.

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to destroy all sessions simply use:

```
Zend_Session::destroy( true );
```

if you want detroy specisic session, use:

```
$sess = 'auth'
$namespace = new \Zend_Session_Namespace( $sess );
$namespace->unsetAll();
```

Comment: But that will destroy a session by the namespace name, I want to destroy by value stored in the session.

Comment: Then just replace the value with null

Comment: ^How do I FIND the session with that particular E-Mail

Comment: Don't get it, all users has their own unique sessions, so you destroy session only for current user

Comment: ^Basically, I am implementing a force logout. Now, I need to find a session to destroyit from another session.

Comment: Oh, ok. According to this topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136266/zend-external-logout-ending-other-sessions

save the session id to the database, and then use Zend_Auth::getInstance()->clearIdentity()